# Derivation of rules pertaining to group $S_{3}$, from Artin's Algebra 2e

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

I'm reading Algebra 2e by Michael Artin.  I'd be grateful for any guidance on 2 closely-related questions from Section 2.2, Groups and Subgroups, p. 42, excerpted below.  First, I can understand the purpose and effect of the three rules listed, but I don't understand where they came from.  Second, and similarly, I can see how the six elements of $S_{3}$ are non-overlapping and distinct, but I don't understand how they were derived.  Where does the cancellation law fit in?  (I'm going to press my luck and also ask how $x^{-1}$ in the first equation at the bottom is equal to $x^2$ in the second, by applying the first two rules).  I am hoping these are simple and closely-enough related to hang together.  If not, I would be glad to remove this and repost over a longer period.  Cheers! Text:

To describe [$S_{3}$], we pick two particular permutations in terms of
  which we can write all others. We take the cyclic permutations
  ($\mathbf{1\ 2\ 3}$), and the transposition ($\mathbf{1\ 2}$), and
  label them as $x$ and $y$, respectively.  The rules $x^3 = 1,\ y^2 =
  1,\ yx = x^2y$ are easy to verify.  Using the cancellation law, one
  sees that the six elements $1,\ x,\ x^2,\ y,\ xy,\ x^2y$ are
  distinct. So they are the six elements of the group: $S_{3} = \{1,\ x,\
  x^2,\ y,\ xy,\ x^2y\}$. [...]

The rules [above] suffice for
computation. Any product of the elements $x$ and $y$ and of their
inverses can be shown to be equal to one of the products by applying
the rules repeatedly. To do so, we move all occurrences of $y$ to the
right side using the last rule, and we use the first two rules to keep
the exponents small.  For instance,

$x^{-1}y^3x^2y = x^2yx^2y = x^2(yx)xy
= x^2(x^2y)xy = xyxy = x(x^2y)y = 1$.

Comment: The reason $x^{-1}=x^2$ is that $1=x^3 = x^2x$; since the only element that when multiplied by $x$ yields $1$ is $x^{-1}$, it follows that $x{-1}=x^2$. The cancellation law comes in when showing the elements are distinct: if $x=x^2$, then cancelling we would get $x=1$, which is false; if $x^2=xy$, then cancelling $x$ we would get $x=y$, which is false. Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you understand how to multiply permutations? The rule $yx=x^2y$, for example, is just saying $$(1\ 2)(1\ 2\ 3)=(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2)$$ and that is easy to verify if you know how to multiply permutations.

The cancellation law tells you, for example, that $x^2$ and $xy$ are distinct: if you had $x^2=xy$, then, by cancellation, you'd have $x=y$, which is manifestly false.

$x^3=1$ implies $(x)(x^2)=1$ which says $x^2$ is the inverse of $x$.